# join 3 tables with where clause

Tags: php, mysql

This query performs three JOIN operations with 3 tables. But is not ok i see..i'm trying to output all the rows in echo, but i have bad luck.

Mysql table columns:

```
tours
------
titlu_slider | desc_slider | poza_slider | poza_articol | pret

tours_review 
----------
name | time_added | review_text

tours_overview
------------
descriere | titlu_box1 | desc_box1 | titlu_box2 | desc_box2 | titlu_box3 | desc_box3 | titlu_box4 | desc_box4
```

Php code:

```
<?php 
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "fidodido", "antonytravel");
 $q = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tours  INNER JOIN tours_review INNER JOIN tours_overview  WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$titlu_slider=$row['titlu_slider'];
$desc_slider=$row['desc_slider'];
$poza_slider=$row['poza_slider'];
$poza_articol=$row['poza_articol'];
$pret=$row['pret'];
## Review table
$name_review=$row['name'];
$time_added=$row['time_added'];
$review_text=$row['review_text'];
## Overview table
$descriere=$row['descriere'];
$titlu_box1=$row['titlu_box1'];
$desc_box1=$row['desc_box1'];
$titlu_box2=$row['titlu_box2'];
$desc_box2=$row['desc_box2'];
$titlu_box3=$row['titlu_box3'];
$desc_box3=$row['desc_box3'];
$titlu_box4=$row['titlu_box4'];
$desc_box4=$row['desc_box4'];

    echo '<section class="parallax_window_in" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="'.$poza_slider.'" data-natural-width="1400" data-natural-height="470">
        <div id="sub_content_in">
            <div id="animate_intro">
                <h1>'.$titlu_slider.'</h1>
                <p>"'.$desc_slider.'"</p>
            </div>

        </div>';
```

Some help needed..thanx.

Comment: We know absolutely nothing about those 3 tables! Would you like us to guess how they join? I could invent some very interesting (but irrelevant) column names for you. (i.e. tell us what column are in each table, at the very least)

Comment: "But I have bad luck" is not a particularly useful description of the problem...

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question

Comment: Have you listed EVERY column from those 3 tables?

Comment: yes, is all there

Comment: then I have absolutely no idea how those 3 tables will join.  "the review table should reference the tour identity, and the overview table should reference the tour identity" `tabela de revizuire ar trebui să facă trimitere la identitatea turului, iar tabela de prezentare ar trebui să facă trimitere la identitatea turului`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify how how the tables relate to each other which might look something like the on conditions shown below (which are just guesses)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tours t
INNER JOIN tours_review trev ON t.id = trev.tour_id
INNER JOIN tours_overview tovr ON = t.id = tovr.tour_id
WHERE t.id = $whatever
```

You then face the issue of what type of join because if you have a tour with no reviews then you probably still want to list it. For that type of relationship you need an "outer join".

```
SELECT * 
FROM tours t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tours_review trev ON t.id = trev.tour_id
INNER JOIN tours_overview tovr ON = t.id = tovr.tour_id
WHERE t.id = $whatever
```

If every every tour has an "overview" then that can remain an "inner join"

**EDIT:** Please note that you need to **prefix EVERY column reference** with a table name or table alias (I have used table aliases to make the query shorter). If you don't do this your query may fail, e.g. if every table has a column `id` and you just ask for `where id = 123` the query will not know which table to use and the query would error.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Answer (score 0):

INNER join shows the records if there are matching record. Use OUTER join to show all records if it does not exists on other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things in your query. Specifically related to the fields that link the tables. To do these joins the best practice is to name each table and then use that name to in an ON statement to JOIN the tables

So

```
SELECT * FROM tours 
INNER JOIN tours_review
INNER JOIN tours_overview  
WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'].""
```

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM tours AS t 
INNER JOIN tours_review AS r ON r.somefield = t.somefield  
INNER JOIN tours_overview AS o ON o.somefield = t.somefield  
WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'].""
```

MySQL can't join tables if it doesn't know what is connecting them.